# Joining 3 mysql tables

Tags: mysql, join

To read and output information about our network license I run a script every few minutes which calls a command line utility and dump the information in 3 mysql tables. Now I would like to get the active sessions and group name where the user belongs to (if the user is member of a group).

The 3 tables I use are:

Table: lm_session

- Featureid (holds the feature id the session is connected to)
- Username (the person using the license)
- Workstation (system connected to the license)
- In (datetime of starting the software)
- Out (datetime of closing the software)
- Key ( session id)
- Active (yes/no)

Table lm_group

- Featureid (holds the feature id the group is connected to
- Name (name of the group)
- License (number of  licenses for the group)

Table lm_group_user

- Group_id (Group Id the user is connected to)
- Feature_id (Feature id *probably unnecessary)
- Username (username)

At this moment I have a query like this

```
SELECT s.*, g.* FROM lm_session AS s 
LEFT JOIN lm_group_user AS u ON s.user = u.user 
LEFT JOIN lm_group AS g ON g.id = u.group_id 
WHERE s.feature_id = :featureid AND s.active = 1
```

I do get all the users that having an active session, but the name of the group is not found properly. If a user is member of multiple groups, the s.user = u.user only finds the first group. The result is not based on a combination of s.user = u.user AND g.id = u.group_id

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Surely you mean `lm_session as s` in order for `s.*` to work...

Comment: Perhaps you ran into associativity issue, like in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/nested-join-optimization.html in short `A j B j C` is either `(A j B) j C` or `A j (B j C)` and you are not explicit as to which you want.

Answer (score 0):

i have found error in your sql query in first line:

SELECT s.*, g.* FROM lm_session AS s ( not session )

since you are using s as alias in rest of query, but in first line you defined session as alias so that was wrong. try only s as alias in first line.

cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the query below:

```
SELECT
s.Username, 
s.Featuredid,
g.Name AS groupname

FROM lm_session s 
JOIN lm_group_user gu ON s.Username = gu.Username
LEFT JOIN lm_group g ON s.Featuredid = g.Featuredid

WHERE s.Active = 1
```

Optional:
Add
`GROUP BY a.Username` 
(If an user have multiple session in the `lm_session` table you might want to add this line to avoid duplicates, but you can start running this query without it see what happens. Since I was thinking an user might have multiple session in different software )