# MySQL removing a link table and joining 3 tables into one

Tags: mysql, join, django-cms

I have a database that has an extraneous database table for product text content which was added via a djangocms placeholder field. I am looking to move this content back into a single table.

My three tables are:

products_product:

```
+------------+------------+
| product_id | content_id |
+------------+------------+
|        374 |       1919 |
+------------+------------+
```

cms_cmsplugin:

```
+----------------+------+
| placeholder_id |  id  |
+----------------+------+
|           1919 | 2042 |
+----------------+------+
```

and cmsplugin_text:

```
+------------------+------------------+
| cmsplugin_ptr_id |       body       |
+------------------+------------------+
|             2042 | <p>some_html</p> |
+------------------+------------------+
```

I am looking to remove the link table and add the cmsplugin_text body directly into the products_product table with a field name of text_content. So far I've been looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25135692/joining-3-mysql-tables) questions and have come up with the following:

```
INSERT INTO
products_product(content_id, text_content)

SELECT
p.content_id,
cpt.body as text_content

FROM products_product p
JOIN cms_cmsplugin cms ON p.content_id = cms.placeholder_id
LEFT JOIN cmsplugin_text cpt ON cms.id = cpt.cmsplugin_ptr_id
```

Which unfortunately hasn't worked and just made a mess of my products_product table.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  AFAIK, you would be _de_-normalizing your database by doing this.

Comment: The extra field was initially added as a django-cms placeholder field which has been confusing for our site admins. They would like to be able to edit the whole of the product in one place and so I felt that it would be a good idea to move this information back into the product itself.

Comment: If you need the link table for any other reason, then I see no reason to remove the `cmsplugin_text` table.  If you _don't_ need the link table, then you should remove it completely.

Comment: Why are you running an insert statement?  Are you purposely trying to duplicate your data?  Surely it's violating the primary key on your products_product table?

Comment: Its currently there because I'm trying to pull the product information out of a legacy system. Once I've got the information in the format that I want I'm going to move it into another system entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you add the column in products_product update:

```
UPDATE products, cms_cmsplugin, cmsplugin_text 
SET products.body = cmsplugin_text.body
WHERE product.content_id = cmsplugin_text.placeholder_id
AND cmsplugin_text.id = cmsplugin_ptr_id
```

Comment: Took a little formatting but that's what I was after, simple and perfect. thank you!